# What is Scaffolding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scaffolding

I am having a question on scaffolding. Can someone explain what it does and how it works. I have search Google but I couldn't find anything that explained all the steps that happens.

Comment: Sorry, there is tones of information about scaffolding, I just don't believe you didn't find anything

Comment: I couldn't find anything about the database interactions

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When I run the command:

```
rails generate scaffold peoples name:string age:integer
```

The following happens:

+ Rails connects to the database (defined in databases.yml) and creates a new table called peoples 
+ In that table it creates two columns named name and age 
+ Now it creates the web page that allows you to interface with the table

Scaffolding gives you a quick start on your Ruby on Rails projects.

Comment: This is incorrect, Rails does not create the table nor the columns in those tables. It creates the migrations necessary to update the database with them.

Answer (score 2):

A simple search in [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=rails%20scaffolds&oq=rails%20scaffolds&aqs=chrome.0.69i57j0l3j69i62l2.1989j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) provides a lot of information. Also wikipedia

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scaffold_(programming)

Long story short a scaffold is simply a utility that most MVC web frameworks provide to create the necessary code/files for simple CRUD operations in the application.

In Rails, this means it will create the following from bottom up:

**Active Record/Models**

1. **Migrations**: These are used to create the necessary tables/columns for the model.
2. **Models**: Self explanatory, class of the model that subclasses from `ActiveRecord::Base`

**Resource Routes**

1. **resources: :model**: It generates the CRUD routes: `index`, `show`, `new`, `create`, `edit`, `update`, `destroy` by placing the `resources: :model_name` line in the `routes.rb` file.

**ActionController**

1. **Controller**: The controller that ties in the routes with the models and views with necessary code to perform the CRUD operations.

**ActionView**

1. **Views**: The views that display a very simplistic UI for performing the CRUD operations.
2. **Assets**: The javascripts, images, css, that are used in the views. This is very modular thanks to the assets pipeline.

It creates a bunch of other stuff based on your choices of test libraries. You can actually see what it's doing by just running `rails scaffold SomeModel`.